# Creating an if statement with a indexerror - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to create a game similar to snake. The difference is that a food ration is recieved by using randint and the player will then be able to choose in which direction the snake should grow, the starting position is also randomly chosen. The game field is built with a matrix and therefore it's possible to grow "into the walls" by chosing a growth direction that makes the list go out of range.

My question is if it's possible to create an if statemant that would end the game with a "game over" if the player chose to grow in a way that makes the list go out of range, something like:

```
if IndexError: list index out of range : 
         print("Game over")
```

With the exception handling my code would look something like this:

```
 try :

    if p == 0:
        table[x][y] = "+"
    elif p == 1:
        table[x][y] = "+"
        table[x][y+1] = "+"
    elif p == 2:
        table[x][y] = "+"
        table[x][y+1] = "+"
        table[x][y+2] = "+"
    else:
        table[x][y] = "+"
        table[x][y+1] = "+"
        table[x][y+2] = "+"
        table[x][y+3] = "+"
 except IndexError :
                 print ("Game Over")
```

But I'm getting the error "unindent does not match any outher indentation level"

Comment: that's because your code is not properly indented.

Comment: Make sure that the try and except statements are at the same indentation, that all of the if/elif/else inside of them have the same indentation, and that all of the content of each if/elif/else state has the same indentation. Even a single space will screw everything up!

Comment: Oh! I didn't know the indentation was that importan! Thanks a lot, it seems like it's working now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions) :

```
 try :
     #your code
 except IndexError:
    print "Game Over"
```

Comment: try :
     
        if p == 0:
            table[x][y] = "+"
        elif p == 1:
            table[x][y] = "+"
            table[x][y+1] = "+"
        elif p == 2:
            table[x][y] = "+"
            table[x][y+1] = "+"
            table[x][y+2] = "+"
        else:
            table[x][y] = "+"
            table[x][y+1] = "+"
            table[x][y+2] = "+"
            table[x][y+3] = "+"
     except IndexError :
                     print ("Game Over")

Comment: Sorry for that! I ment to ask if it's possible to write a if statement inside the exception handling? My code I want inside the exception handling looks like what I wrote above!

Comment: @user1832337 don't post your code in comments, It's hard to understand. Better post it in the question body.

Comment: yea, I'm sorry for that, I'll repost in now.